# How do I put a clickable image over a QuickTime video on a web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, quicktime

I have a website that runs on WordPress. There is a DIV in the header that contains an embedded QuickTime video (controls are turned off and need to stay like that). I have an image that is supposed to go over the video, and when the user clicks on it, the video should be revealed and play.

I think that if I messed around with the CSS and Javascript for long enough, I could make the image go away and revel the embedded video when clicked on, but I don't know how to make the video start on that same "onclick" event. Another note here: I prefer to use jQuery to do this, since that's what I usually work with. But whatever works works.

This is driving me crazy because I can't find any good information on how to do this! Thank you so much in advance for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a DIV that contains the video, you can create another same-sized DIV that contains your image. Finally, set the image DIV with higher [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_z-index.asp) and float it over the video DIV.

I think this should work.

Comment: I did do that, but I got into trouble trying to use JavaScript to create the effect where the user clicks on the image and then the video not only appears but also plays. I ended up getting help with a script from someone, though. Thanks for offering a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no good way to do this when rendering the video using the QuickTime plugin. Plugins are optimized for performance and typically render above the rest of the "native" elements within your page.

I seem to recall there's a wmode="transparent" attribute or "opaque" that was introduced recently to the plugin similar to  what's used with the Flash plugin, but the performance will typically suffer because the plugin renderer will often need to switch to rendering in software as it composites the video with the element you have on top of it, and possibly elements beneath it as well.

The easiest thing to do is to simply use a video element to play the media you want on your page. At that point it is an element like any other on the page and interacts seamlessly with the z-index ordering of positioned elements.

An example of the usage is here: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/introduction-html5-video/

You may need to nest differently encoded videos as video elements in the page so various user agents with support for different codes can play the video. But just adding the video element and pointing it at your current QuickTime video will work as well as a simple object using the QT plugin.

Comment: Luckily, I got someone to write me a small script for this, and it works. I did end up getting the person who supplied the video to provide it in a smaller format, thankfully. It took far too long to load.